# Keras - Mean Squared Error (MSE) calculation definition for images?

Tags: image, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I am using

```
loss = 'mse'
```

in Keras for an autoencoder model that reconstructs greyscale images. My batch size is 1. A single loss value is being produced during training.

I can't seem to find anywhere an answer to this question. How does Keras calculate this MSE loss value for these 2 images? They're represented as 2d NumPy arrays. Does it compute the squared difference between each pixel and then divide by the number of pixels (considering the batch size is 1)?

Is this process the same if the input is more than 1 greyscale image into the model; computing the squared pixel difference across all the images, then dividing by the total number of pixels in all the images?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

This is the code for the mse, the operations (difference and square) are bitwise (pixel by pixel), then it computes the mean, so it divides for the number of values (pixel).